# naive bayes, 15 features on 35instances dataset - 7 classes

Tags: java, android, dataset, classification

I'm doing my course project which contains a classification problem. It is about the classifying smartphone moves into 7 different classes. I'm using Accelerometer (LinearAcceleration). I've extracted 15 features (5 for each axis) which are:
 - mean (time)
 - std (time)
 - DC Offset, mean (frequency)
 - Energy (frequency)
 - Entropy (frequency)

Features that are in frequency domain are obtained through Fast Fourier Transform.

My app wants the user to train classifier with max 5 instances per class (user performs five times the movement for each class) and till now I've used implementation of Naive Bayes from WEKA library.

My problem is - i'm not satisfied with the accuracy of the classifier. Is there any other classifier that would perform better for such small dataset?

Later on, the app will gather more instances and add them to the training dataset, then retrain the classifier but at the begining I can't ask the user for more than 5 instances per class.

What would you propose?

Comment: You could try using SVM, it generally performs better than NB, especially with fewer samples.

Answer (score 0):

naive Bayes works well when your features don't effect each other...
 but it works very well when you have small data-set
on the other hand you can try logistic regression or SVM

but in real World scenarios your algorithm doesn't matter that much , your Dataset(instances,features) is more important